# Folder access in another domain

Tags: web, dns

I have a site with this simple structure:

```
\public_html
  {files}.php
  \files
  \es
```

For the public_html I created a domain site.com and for the public_html/es I created spanishsite.com domain. The problem is: I need to access the FILES directory in the Spanish domain... so, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Where is this *FILES* directory?  How are you trying to access it; what method/protocol/language?

Comment: files (sorry about CAPS) directory is on public_html root directory and I'm using only php. I'm trying to access files inside this directory with relative path, for example: "../files/file01.pdf" from spanishsite.com
And I know I can not do this, but how can I do this? Did u understand?

Comment: Why can' you do this?  What error do you get?  It seems like the logical way for PHP to reference those files. (Remember PHP runs server-side).

Comment: I can, but it doesn't work. Imagine:
1) site.com/es = sitespanish.com
2) I want to access a file in site.com/files/file01.pdf, using sitespanish.com

Just do ../files/file01.pdf from any php file on sitespanish.com doesn't work. I'd like to how to do that.

The problem is how to access files/ folder through any spanishsite.com php file.

Thanks


EDIT: The error is, of course, Error 404 - object not found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you're trying to link to the file, rather than just read it from PHP.
Of course, since you're serving `/es/` on that domain, you web-server won't serve files above that directory.

You've two choices:

1) The easiest, just symlink `files` into `es/` and link to that:

```
cd es/
ln -s ../files
```

In your PHP file, link to files/, just as if it where inside `es/`.
If your server runs windows, you'll have to use `mklink` instead of ln.  Check the manual to know the exact arguments you need.

2) Configure your webserver to serve the `/files/` directory of the spanish domain from a different path; the path where the `files` is currently located to be precise.  How to do this will depends strongly on what webserver you're using, and you'll have to reconfigure this any time you change it, as well as replicate this configuration on any test servers, etc.